# Android Studio: Can not install App after changed package name

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have created a new project with a new package name (company name), then copied source code from the old project to a new project.

Everything worked well.
The problem is:
If the old app was installed on a device, then I can not install a new app on that device.
If I remove the old app (of the old project), I could install a new app (of the new project) normally.

I'm installing by debugging from Android Studio.

Please help if you met this case.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Guys, why down vote, I have researched, but no result

Comment: Hi Dieter, I tried renaming package, clean build, check manifest, applicationid. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am having this same problem. what there ever a solution?

Comment: sorry shellman, not yet

Comment: I ended up creating a new project, and copying over all the files manually via the command line, and then fixing the package names. That worked fine. Thankfully the project only has about 10 classes at the moment so it wasn't too onerous. I don't remember exactly the message I was getting, but in the android studio log one of the ADB commands would not stop using the old package name and I simply could not figure out where that was being set, even after grepping through all the files on disk.

Comment: If you keep using old package, can user install both 2 apps of you?

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like your applicationId in your build.gradle (app) hasn't been changed. I would check under defaultConfig and see if it is the same as your old project and change it:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Comment: Hi hopeman: When I created new project with new company name, the appicationId was changed

Comment: did you check in your manifest bei package?
`<manifest
    package="com.xxx.xxx"`

Comment: Yes, I checked manifest, also searched all project, there is no name of old package

Comment: Hey Vai Dan, I would try using the adb shell to see if for some reason the package names are the same. With: `adb shell pm list packages` you can see a list of packages from the apps installed. Install the old app and check the package name, then install the new app and check the package name... alternatively you could share your repository, if this is possible.

Comment: Hi hopeman, I checked like your solution. Package name is correct. If install new app, it show new package name. if install old app, it show old package name. AND there is always have package as [old.packagename].debug

Comment: It's a little hard to debug the problem... if you have your code in a repository I could take a look...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

old or other package names are available in Manifest file

Check `<provider>`, `<uses-permission>`, and `<permission>` tags in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<provider    
    android:authorities="com.your.package.fileProvider"
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.google.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.google.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new application. I copied my old app and I changed the application ID (not necessary to change the package name and usages). But I faced the same problem (I was not able to install the new app on the device if the old app is installed. if I uninstalled the old app it works).
**The solution** to install the new app while keeping the old app installed on the mobile device is to change   **authorities** under **provider** in Manifest file:

This is how it was:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.oldappname.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
</provider>
```

I changed **oldappname** in authorities to **newappname**:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.newappname.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
</provider>
```

Hope that will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not happy with the answers above, try this. This worked for me.

After making sure that you did all the necessary "find and replace" of old package name to new package name correctly, try "Invalidate Caches and Restart" option in Android SDK IDE from the "File" menu. Things will work fine once your IDE is back.

Answer (score 0):

'Sync Project with Gradle Files' by hand works for me.

In my case, application id is not configured in the build.gradle file, but in a kotlin file. Change the application id and other things in the kotlin file would not trigger a gradle sync hint in Android Studio. Re-create a 'Run Configurations' or 'Clean/Rebuild' or 'Restart Android Studio' both didn't work. I also search the old package name in the project dir and found nothing, which makes me think of gradle. After the gradle sync, the error solved.